# Filter pandas dataframe by comparing column to multiindex group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame like the following:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', \
                               'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz'],\
                        'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'one', \
                               'two', 'two', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two'],\
                        'C' : pandas.np.random.randn(12)})

df

    A    B         C
0   foo  one -0.241101
1   foo  one -0.658436
2   foo  two  0.300752
3   foo  two -0.589445
4   bar  one  1.775511
5   bar  one  0.068603
6   bar  two -0.464550
7   bar  two -0.621055
8   baz  one -1.469311
9   baz  one  0.490963
10  baz  two -0.606491
11  baz  two -0.006323
```

What I want to do is to filter those values in C which are smaller than the mean of the group (A,B).

The grouping works:

```
groups = df.groupby([df.A, df.B])
upper_bound = groups.C.mean()
upper_bound

A    B  
bar  one    0.922057
     two   -0.542803
baz  one   -0.489174
     two   -0.306407
foo  one   -0.449768
     two   -0.144346
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

But how do I filter now so that (in this example) row `1   foo  one -0.658436` would be removed

I tried the following things:

```
df_ = df.loc[df.C <= upper_bound.loc[df.A, df.B]]
```

But that says

```
'None of [0     foo\n1     foo\n2     foo\n3     foo\n4     bar\n5     bar\n6     bar\n7     bar\n8     baz\n9     baz\n10    baz\n11    baz\nName: A, dtype: object] are in the [index]'
```

And I tried:

```
df_ = df.loc[df.C <= upper_bound[df.A, df.B]]
```

and that gives me:

```
pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3824)()
pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3492)()
TypeError:
```

The reason I am trying it this way is because I already (at least I think that) managed to do the 'same' thing but with one-level groups:

```
groups = df.groupby([df.A])
upper_bound = groups.C.mean()
df_ = df.loc[df.C <= upper_bound.loc[df.A]
```

And that actually gets rid of everyhing in df where C is below upper_bound.

Any ideas in what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You compared the result of groupby `upper_bound` to `df['C']`, but they have different number of elements. Use `transform` to have the mean for each line existing witin each group and compare it to `df['C']`. Apply this mask with `loc`:

```
import numpy as np

df.loc[df['C']>=df.groupby(['A','B']).transform(np.mean)['C'],]

Out[13]:
      A    B         C
0   foo  one  0.579987
3   foo  two  1.701136
5   bar  one  1.955158
7   bar  two  0.943862
9   baz  one -0.628506
10  baz  two  1.097203
```

Comment: Hey thanks very much! That actually works so far! :)
But I still dont understand what I have done wrong. Can you elaborate on the different-number-of-elements argument? I thought that by selecting `upper_bound.loc[df.A, df.B]]` I would get the right amount exactly as in the one-level group operation...